# How to split a large query in command line?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, docker

I installed oracle db version 19c in my docker environment and set up a database filled with dummy data. However, when I try to run a very large query I get the error:

SP2-0341: line overflow during variable substitution (>3000 characters at line 1).

I tried splitting it up with linebreaks but depending on how I split it I get all kinds of errors like:

ERROR at line 2: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

or

ERROR at line 2:
SP2-0341: line overflow during variable substitution (>3000 characters at line 3)

The query is formatted as

```
SELECT AA.n_name AS AA_n_name, AA.n_nationkey AS ...
FROM nation AS AA FULL OUTER JOIN supplier...
WHERE (AC.p_partkey = ... AND...) OR((AC.p_partkey = ...)); -- The where part is over 5000 characters long--
```

Is there an alternative or solution to tackling this in the command line? I tried running the query as a sql file as well and hit a 4999 limit. I am on a Ubuntu server if that would help and any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: You can insert newlines anywhere in your script

Comment: When I said linebreaks I meant newlines, so unfortunately I am still stuck.

Comment: What is the length of your entire query and why it is so huge?

Comment: It is over 6000 characters long and it is for a project I am working on.

Comment: Then looks like the query is malformed, because line breakes are allowed anywhere and never produce any error.  I cannot imagine handwritten query that is 6000 long and is located in a single line: no one will write it correctly in one attempt and for readability it should be written step by step with appropriate formatting. So sad, but looks like the question cannot be answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the environment that you're working in, but generally you are able to continue a command onto the next line by ending the line with a 'back slash' \.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I tried it earlier but unfortunately it leads to the error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended .

Comment: The query was indeed malformed and when fixed this solution did work.